# Secret key formed by the combination of several keys

Tags: keys

I think there exists an algorithm to create a key from the combination of a group of keys in such a way that if I encrypt a message using the key formed from the combination, I should be able to decrypt it using any one of the keys from the group. Any idea?

Comment: Are we talking about [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing)?

Comment: @kelalaka: no, it sounds like he wants something that does broadcast encryption (with independently selected keys)

Comment: Situation is of  WSN. I have a base station with list of IDs of all the sensors in it's network. I want base station to do a message broadcast which is encrypted using a combination of all the IDs in it's database and each node which only has it's own ID should be able to decrypt it individually.

Comment: This problem seems a ABE to me, where the policy is a membership in a set of keys. if the secret-key of ID belongs to the set, ID can decrypt the ciphertext.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution would be to encrypt the message under all the different keys and concatenate the ciphertexts. However, this obviously has a large blow-up in terms of ciphertext length.

An idea to decrease the blowup would be to encrypt the message under a new short key $k'$ to get a ciphertext $c$, then encrypt $k'$ under all the IDs $k_1,...,k_n$ individually and concatenate the results to $c$ and broadcast the concatenation.

This may not be great in practice but it has an asymptotic rate of $1$, which is better than the trivial solution's rate of $1/n$.

One caveat for both the above solutions is that there would have to be some ordering on the stations, and the stations would have to know their place in the ordering.